# How does the get(key) work even after the hashtable has grown in size!

Tags: java

If a Hashtable is of size 8 originally and we hit the load factor and it grows double the size. How is get still able to retrieve the original values ... so say we have a hash function key(8) transforms into 12345 as the hash value which we mod by 8 and we get the index 7 ... now when the hash table size grows to 16 ...for key(8) we get 12345 .. if we mod it by 16 we will get a different answer! So how do i still retrieve the original key(8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't Java specific - when a hash table grows (in most implementations I know of), it has to reassess the keys of all hashed objects, and place them into their new, correct bucket based on the number of buckets now available.

This is also why resizing a hashtable is generally considered to be an "expensive" operation (compared to many others) - because it has to visit all of the stored items within it.

Answer (score 3):

The hash value used to look up the value comes from the key object itself, not the container.

That's why objects uses as keys in a Map must be immutable.  If the `hashCode()` changes, you won't be able to find your key or value again.

Comment: In his example the hash value isn't changing.  The asker is wondering about how the same hash value is found when the Hashtable grows, thus its modulus can change, meaning the same value is not likely to be found in the same bucket.  Excellent point on keys being immutable though.  I never thought about whether or not I could lose my key-value pair in a hashtable/hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

It is all implementation dependent, but a [rehash](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#rehash%28%29) will occur when it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the source for the HashMap class, in the `transfer()` method, which is called by the `resize()` method.

```
    /**
     * Transfers all entries from current table to newTable.
     */
    void transfer(Entry[] newTable) {
        Entry[] src = table;
        int newCapacity = newTable.length;
        for (int j = 0; j < src.length; j++) {
            Entry<K,V> e = src[j];
            if (e != null) {
                src[j] = null;
                do {
                    Entry<K,V> next = e.next;
                    int i = indexFor(e.hash, newCapacity);
                    e.next = newTable[i];
                    newTable[i] = e;
                    e = next;
                } while (e != null);
            }
        }
    }
```

In this HashTable implementation you can follow *exactly* how each entry is stored in the new (twice as big) storage array.  The capacity of the new array is used in determining which slot each item will be stored.  The hashcode of the keys does not change (it is in fact not even recomputed, but retrieved from the public field named `hash` in each `Entry` object, where it is stored), what changes is the result of the `indexFor()` call:

```
    /**
     * Returns index for hash code h.
     */
    static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
        return h & (length-1);
    }
```

which takes the hash code and the new storage array's length and returns the index in the new array.

So a client's new call to `get()` will go through the same `indexFor()` call, which will also use the new storage array's length, and all will be well.